# TVInputService HDMI channel are not detected by "Live Channels" app

Tags: android-tv

I have developed a TVInputService for HDMI passthrough Input. And this app has System privilage and part of my Android-TV platform. Also installed "Live Channels" app which should detect all custom TVInputService channels available in system. And if there is any searchable channel available, "Live Channels" will show up in Launcher. But my TvInputService provided HDMI-passthrough channel is not detected by LiveChannels. If I install this sample apk/channels, 
https://github.com/googlesamples/androidtv-sample-inputs
then only LiveChannels is shown up and I can also see my HDMI channel as well.
What info. is not passed to LiveChannles to detect my TVInputService?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there's some tagging issue preventing the Live Channels app from correctly seeing your app.

Make sure you have these tags in your manifest:

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.software.LIVE_TV"
    android:required="true" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.software.LEANBACK"
    android:required="true" />
```